# How to access a single attribute of associated model inside a loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I extremely need your assistance. I have many to many :through relationship models: Product, Category and Categorization(as intermediate model). In my view I want to iterate through @products and fetch category's 
field "title" on each iteration.

Here's my view:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="row">
                    <section id="projects">
                        <ul id="thumbs">
                            <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                        <% @products.each do |product| %>
                            <% product.categories.each do |category| %>
                                <li class="item-thumbs col-md-4 <%= category.title %> ">  
                            <% end %>
                               <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                                <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery"    title="The City" >
                                    <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                    <%= icon 'font-icon-plus' %>
                                </a>
                                <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                                <%= image_tag product.product_images, alt: product.description %>
                                <p><%= product.price %></p>
                            </li>                            
                            <!-- End Item Project -->  
                        <% end %>   
                        </ul>

                    </section>

                </div>
```

As you see, I need to get category's title on each iteration so as to insert it to li "class" and link each product tab to a menu "li".

The problem is that when I iterate through @categories inside @products loop, it executes just once therefore I don't get category's title for each product.

Comment: What executes just once? This looks like it will go through each product in `@products` and then, for every category that each of these products has, generate your `<li>` element.

Comment: I was supposed to fetch 'title' attribute on each iteration of @products just like it shown below)) Thank you for your effort as well)))

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your loop is repeatedly creating the opening `li` tag rather than collecting all the category titles like you want, resulting in invalid HTML. Try writing your markup like so instead:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="row">
        <section id="projects">
            <ul id="thumbs">
                <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                <% @products.each do |product| %>
                    <!-- RELEVANT CHANGES RIGHT HERE! -->
                    <li class="item-thumbs col-md-4 <%= product.categories.pluck(:title).join(' ') %>">
                        <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                        <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="The City" >
                            <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                            <%= icon 'font-icon-plus' %>
                        </a>
                        <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                        <%= image_tag product.product_images, alt: product.description %>
                        <p><%= product.price %></p>
                    </li>                            
                    <!-- End Item Project -->
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

This uses Rails' handy [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) method to grab all the relevant category titles directly from the database, then joins them together with spaces to make a valid `class` string. Is this the effect you were looking for?

Comment: Thank you a lot, It works exactly like expected. You released me from week torture)))